# Get unique array elements in MongoDB by "master" element

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb rows with array element which looks like this:

```
{"data" : [1, 111]}
{"data" : [222, 1]}
{"data" : [1, 333]}
{"data" : [2, 444]}
```

How to get unique array elements by "master" element. So for example "master" element is **1** I should get result: `[111, 222, 333]` and **not** `444`, because that array does not contain **1**. If master element would be **2**, the result should be: `[444]`

---

I tried something like this aggregation. Is it correct? Are there any performance issues? What indecies should be on table to make it fast?

```
[
  {$match: {"data": 1}},
  {$project : {a : '$data'}},
  {$unwind: '$a'},
  {$group: {_id: 'a', items: {$addToSet: '$a'}}}
]
```

Comment: You description is not clear. Can you clarify it a little bit more? Why in the second example, the result is not [2, 444], but only [444]?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic it could be `[2, 444]`. I missed 2 because I already know it as master key

Comment: I still don't get it. You want to return all arrays that contain "master" element?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic I want one array (set) with all unique elemenst from arrays where master key is present

Comment: I see... But in your example, why when master key is "4", the result is [444]... Shouldn't be an empty array?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic Ooops! Sorry, my bad. Key should be 2 in second example :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Aggregation` framework:

- `$match` to filter all documents that have "master" key in the "data" array.
- `$group` to concatenate "data" arrays of all documents in one property called "result" and `$filter` to filter our "master" element from "data" arrays. ("result" will be an array that will have all documents "data" arrays as elements).
- `$reduce` with `$concatArrays` to concatenate all "data" arrays inside "result" property.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      data: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      result: {
        $addToSet: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$data",
            "cond": {
              "$ne": [
                "$$this",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      result: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$result",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Be aware that the "master" element has to be dynamically populated in first stage for `$match` pipeline, as well as in the second stage when performing filtering with `$filter` operator.

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/EtYwOqAE-PE

Comment: Wow, it's very interesting. I'm going to learn what exactly you did here. Also, can you please tell me what indecies I need for such aggregation for better performance?

Comment: I added some description on the answer. Check if it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by indexes?

Comment: You could use `$addToSet: $filter:$data`  in which case you won't need `$project`

Comment: You are totally right, I updated my code. Thank you. @styvane

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic I mean indexes for mongodb collection to make this aggregate pipeline fast and not perform fullscan

Comment: if you have an index on data(multikey index) it can make it much faster i think, all arrays that don't have the master key will go fast, but multikey indexes are kinda of big, try it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works also

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lb6FRZ-jhyh)

- keeps only the arrays that contain the master key
- unwind them
- group by `{"_id" 1}` is like group by null, all make it true, just added to have the master key as _id (on the group `$$REMOVE` system variable is used to not add the master key)

Query (where you see 1 put your master key, or a variable)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "data": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": 1,
      "members": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$ne": [
                "$data",
                1
              ]
            },
            "$data",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```